# Convert a string to an 8-bit signed integer in python

Tags: python, ctypes, signed, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to patch together a motor control system using python and ctypes and one of the things I need to do is take an text input and convert it to an 8-bit signed integer.

Below is the documentation for the function I'm trying to call. The text that should be input into the program is 'EPOS2'

[image]

The data type definition is as shown below (note that 'char*' equates to an 8-bit signed integer)

[image]

So How do I convert 'EPOS2' to a value between -128 and 127?

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
import ctypes #import the module

lib=ctypes.WinDLL(example.dll) #load the dll

VCS_OpenDevice=lib['VCS_OpenDevice'] #pull out the function

#per the parameters below, each input is expecting (as i understand it) 
#an 8-bit signed integer (or pointer to an array of 8 bit signed integers, 
#not sure how to implement that)
VCS_OpenDevice.argtypes=[ctypes.c_int8, ctypes.c_int8, ctypes.c_int8, ctypes.c_int8]

#create parameters for my inputs
DeviceName ='EPOS2'
ProtocolStackName = 'MAXON SERIAL V2'
InterfaceName = 'USB'
PortName = 'USB0'


#convert strings to signed 8-bit integers (or pointers to an array of signed 8-bit integers)
#code goes here
#code goes here
#code goes here

#print the function with my new converted input parameters


print VCS_OpenDevice(DeviceName,ProtocolStackName,InterfaceName,PortName)
```

Comment: It's not a `char`, it's a `char*`.  Which is, technically speaking, a pointer to a `char`, but is generally used do denote an array of `chars` terminated with the Null Byte - or a String.  How are you trying to call this function?  Example code will let us know what exactly is missing.

Comment: Could you clarify the use of `ctypes` here? Are you calling another library and want to use it to do that, or can you literally just emulate a structure using the `struct` module?

Comment: I put what I've got currently. Hopefully this sheds some light on what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ctypes`:

```
>>> from ctypes import cast, pointer, POINTER, c_char, c_int
>>> 
>>> def convert(c):
...     return cast(pointer(c_char(c)), POINTER(c_int)).contents.value
... 
>>> map(convert, 'test string')
[116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

Which (as I just found out) matches the output of `ord`:

```
>>> map(ord, 'test string')
[116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

Although your data type definitions list it as a `char`, not a `char*`, so I'm not sure how you'd handle that.

Answer (score 2):

Your interface takes `char*` which are C strings.  The equivalent `ctypes` type is `c_char_p`.  Use:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('example.dll')
VCS_OpenDevice = lib.VCS_OpenDevice
VCS_OpenDevice.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p]

DeviceName ='EPOS2'
ProtocolStackName = 'MAXON SERIAL V2'
InterfaceName = 'USB'
PortName = 'USB0'

print VCS_OpenDevice(DeviceName,ProtocolStackName,InterfaceName,PortName)
```

Also, `WinDLL` is normally only needed for Windows system DLLs.  If your interfaces are declared `__stdcall` in the C header file, `WinDLL` is correct; otherwise, use `CDLL`.

Additionally, your return code is documented as a `DWORD*`, which is a bit strange.  Why not `DWORD`?  If `DWORD*` is correct, to access the value of the DWORD pointed to by the return value, you can use:

```
VCS_OpenDevice.restype = POINTER(c_uint32)
retval = VCS_OpenDevice(DeviceName,ProtocolStackName,InterfaceName,PortName)
print retval.contents.value
```